# Sorting data provided by Redux on componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

**Background**

I have some data coming from a redux store in my React component. I want this data to be sorted initially when it is displayed to the user. I have a sorting reducer and call it in `componentDidMount`. This does not sort the data. I know the sort function and reducer is correct because I call the reducer on a `button` click which does sort the data.

**Example Code**

*Component*

```
class PostsContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeStamp: 'BY_TIMESTAMP',
            voteScore: 'BY_VOTESCORE',
            voteScoreHigh: 'BY_HIGH_VOTESCORE',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.voteScoreHigh);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Posts />
                <div><button onClick={() => this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.timeStamp)}>Sort by Time Stamp</button></div>
                <div><button onClick={() => this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.voteScore)}>Sort by Vote Score</button></div>
                {
                    this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className='cats' key={index}>
                                <h4>{post.timestamp}</h4>
                                <h4>{post.voteScore}</h4>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  boundSortPosts: (attribute) => dispatch(sortPosts(attribute))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsContainer);
```

*Action*

```
export function sortPosts(attribute) {
    return {
        type: SORT_POSTS,
        attribute,
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SORT_POSTS': {
          switch (action.attribute) {
            case 'BY_HIGH_VOTESCORE':
                return state.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
                    return b.voteScore - a.voteScore;
              });
            default:
              return state;
          }
        }
        case SET_POSTS:
            return action.posts;
        default:


 return state;
}
```

}

**Question**

How can I sort the data with my reducer once the initial page load is done?

Answer (score 1):

I would rethink the architecture of your app. The state is a normalized representation of the state of your app. It should contain the information that identifies what your app should display right now.

The fact that `PostsContainer` wants to display your posts sorted in a particular way is a detail that concerns that component. In this case, I would build a selector, that from the state takes the posts as they are and sorts them before displaying them. That selector should be applied in the `mapStateToProps` (the component should now as little about the state as possible, so only the key containing the posts should be passed).

If you are concerned about performance (resorting the list everytime a change in the state happens) or convenience (having to manipulate the state or build views of it yourself), you can consider using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), which actually covers your use case quite well.

Comment: So you are saying, anytime I want to filter data, pass the state from redux to the component and in mapStateToProps filter the data in there. So its only mutating the data in the component and not the store?

Comment: if by mutating the data you mean changing it, that should only happen through actions, which through a reducer lands in the store. In this case, though, you are presenting the store in a different way (sorted), but that is a _view_ of the state, not a change, so that's why I would use a selector that does that. Maybe another part of your app needs to display the store in a second format, and you don't want to save duplicate information. So that's why you "reformat" it by applying a selector that makes it consumable by your component.